# Flask Self Updating variable in render template

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a flask site, and I want to add a countdown timer to a page.
I have a piece of code posting to cd.html, with `return render_template('cd.html', timenow=datetime.now(), endtime=datetime.now()+timedelta(hours=2))`

I have a supporting function to give the difference between the times (endtime - timenow) and convert it into a string to post onto the webpage, however, the difference between the times on the webpage shown is constant throughout... Would there be any way for it to change with each passing second? I don't mind using jinja2 or any other python functions or packages.

Comment: You should definitely use javascript for dynamic changes on your website.

Comment: @blazej The webpage is linked to other pages which depend on the same timer, so I dont think js will cut it, unless i'm wrong

Comment: You can post it on webpage and with it's value start a timer with javascript. And when the time is over you can do what you want.

Comment: @charchit How would I convert a time in python to javascript? I don't think jinja2 lets you add python variables into script tags...

Comment: Also, isn't js in the user time zone? I want all the time methods to be in UTC...

Comment: Jinja do if script is in html file, like `"{{myvar}}"` 《also you can send an ajax request which is sent to flask by javascript and is response is received by javascript.

Comment: You can convert it using [toUTCString()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp&ved=2ahUKEwip0cf5kZLxAhW8zzgGHQuiBbEQFjABegQIBBAF&usg=AOvVaw2QGv0qetR85nwx4_4vbjwX)

Comment: Great, Thanks !